# How to install a specific KB update to a Windows Server 2016 Docker container

Tags: windows, containers, windows-server, windows-server-2016, windows-container

I have a Windows Server 2016 Docker container and I want to apply [a specific KB update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4507704/dst-changes-in-windows-for-brazil-and-morocco) to it. I wonder how to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Your Dockerfile could look like this:

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:ltsc2016
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

RUN Invoke-WebRequest "KB_URL" -OutFile update.exe -UseBasicParsing ; \
Start-Process -FilePath 'update.exe' -ArgumentList '--quiet', '--norestart' -Wait ; \
Remove-Item .\update.exe
```